# form validation and security in php

Tags: php

Hello Stackoverflow engineers. I know this question might sound basic but please i will like to know this. I have a form that i want to check for spam bot attack. I knew spam bot works by filling up form fields.   lets assume that I have an input field with a value and a checkbox that checked.

```
<input type="text" name="myname" value="nancy">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
```

**my question:**
 can spambot be able to remove the content an input box **(nancy)** or uncheck the already checkedbox.

Comment: Yes, spambot can do as it pleases. You must ***always*** validate user entered information on the server-side.

Comment: Please can you elaborate  or give an instance on how spambot can just remove a value(eg. nancy) in a form input. how is that possible. I will like to know. Thanks

Comment: It's not removing anything. it's just a client that can send whatever it wants to the server.

Comment: `document.querySelector("[name=myname]").value = "")`

Comment: @Barmar. thanks for responding. i kown how to do validation and all data in php. front and backend.   my question is assuming I have an input form with a value. can spambot remove the value in the input or uncheck the checkedbox just like the way the used to filling all the form field they see

Comment: As @Barmar stated, a spambot does not have to remove anything from a form.

Comment: thank you. thats what i want